# Creating android application without Android framework

Tags: android, frameworks, arm

In [Android Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCpB7.png) 4th Layer is android Framework which uses JAVA,Kotlin. If I am correct than all applications are made from this framework.

Is there some other non JVM-Language based framework from which I can made Android Apps ?

I tried QT, But It also creates some java files and uses android Framework. Is it even possible to make Android app WITHOUT EVEN ANY PRESENCE OF JAVA ?

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to simply not write in a JVM language, you are welcome to use C/C++ with the NDK, [using `NativeActivity` as your entry point](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity).

If your objective is to avoid the framework classes entirely, you are welcome to build your own fork of Android that contains your own code as native Linux daemons, launched by init scripts or something.

If your objective is to ship an app on the Play Store or through similar channels that avoids the framework classes entirely, AFAIK there is no option for that.

Comment: Android NDK uses clang which produces so slow binaries than gcc .Is there any way of using third party compilers instead if Android NDK ? I know this is not mentioned in Question but ur wisdom is appropriated

Comment: @yojimbooru: "Android NDK uses clang which produces so slow binaries than gcc" -- it seems to be sufficient for game developers, and they have some of the highest performance requirements of anyone on Android. "Is there any way of using third party compilers instead if Android NDK ?" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create an android application without using android framework. At least, for launching your application you will have to use framework functions from "android.os" package.